# UICollectionView crashes when deleting section

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

When using this code

```
  - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
             clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {

            [self removeCompany:companySelectedInActionSheet]; 

            NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:
                          indexPathSelectedInActionSheet.section];
            NSLog(@"IndexSet to delete from collection view: %@",indexSet);
            [self.collectionView deleteSections:indexSet]; 
        }
    }
```

my app crashes sometimes (10% of the time) with this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UICollectionView.m:3700
```

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Is the action sheet, which is presented before the deletion, a potential problem?

Do I need to dismiss it manually before deleting the collection view section?

Comment: Could be that your `UICollectionViewDataSource` still provide cells for this indexSet.

Comment: @gWiz: Will the cells not be deleted automatically when their section gets deleted?

Comment: Only in the UI. But if your `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` still provides them for a deleted indexSet, that could be a problem. I know for example that if you delete your last cell in a tableView but your `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` still provides cells (because for example your array providing them still has items inside), the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your table view  delegate to `nil` on `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: You mean collection view delegate? My view is not disappearing, I am just deleting one section (=row) in the collection view.

Comment: When I set the delegate to `nil` in `viewDidDisappear`, the app does no longer crash when the view disappears, reappears and I delete the section. This is already an improvement. However, when the view reappears, the collection view is sometimes empty (even though the `numberOfSection` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods are called and return correct values). Any ideas on why the collection sometimes remains empty? BTW: Do you mean setting the `delegate` OR the `datasource`
 to `nil`?