# UICollection View Deleting Section

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uicollectionview

I have searched a lot to find a solution to delete section's in a `UICollectionView`
but all the proposed solutions leading to a crash.

The code is I have used is:

```
[categoryCollection performBatchUpdates:^{
        NSIndexSet *indexSet=[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, keys.count-1)];
        [categoryCollection deleteSections:indexSet];

    } completion:nil];
```

Update:

```
 @implementation BooksLayout
 - (void)prepareLayout {
// Registers my decoration views.
[self registerClass:[ShelfView class] forDecorationViewOfKind:[ShelfView kind]];
 }

 - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString  *)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Prepare some variables.
NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *nextCellAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:decorationViewKind withIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect baseFrame = cellAttributes.frame;
CGRect nextFrame = nextCellAttributes.frame;

CGFloat strokeWidth = 8;
CGFloat spaceToNextItem = 0;
if (nextFrame.origin.y == baseFrame.origin.y)
    spaceToNextItem = (nextFrame.origin.x - baseFrame.origin.x - baseFrame.size.width);

// Positions the horizontal line for this item.
    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(10,
                                        baseFrame.origin.y + baseFrame.size.height,
                                        300,
                                        strokeWidth);


layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1;
return layoutAttributes;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
NSArray *baseLayoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
NSMutableArray * layoutAttributes = [baseLayoutAttributes mutableCopy];

for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *thisLayoutItem in baseLayoutAttributes) {
    if (thisLayoutItem.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell) {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *newHorizontalLayoutItem = [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:[ShelfView kind] atIndexPath:thisLayoutItem.indexPath];
            [layoutAttributes addObject:newHorizontalLayoutItem];

    }
}

return layoutAttributes;
}
 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if([sortString isEqualToString:@"title"]){
    NSArray *keys=[bookObj.orderedBooks allKeys];
    keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:
            @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    return [[bookObj.orderedBooks objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}
else
    return bookObj.booksArray.count;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView crashes when deleting section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592632/uicollectionview-crashes-when-deleting-section)

Comment: i tried that solution by making the delegate to nil but still gets a crash

Comment: can you add crash logs?

Comment: Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData numberOfItemsBeforeSection:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionViewData.m:514  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for number of items before section 4 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view'

Comment: can you add code of your collection view datasource methods.

Comment: i have added the methods as update

Comment: What layout you have defined for collection view?

Comment: i have used a  custom layout of UICollectionViewFlowLayout class

Comment: Can you add code for that too.

Comment: after deleting your sections, are you calling reloadData method???

Comment: no,reload wont work it will give the same error

Comment: yes, that was my point, and from where you are calling performBatchUpdates method. which you mentioned in the first part in the question?

Comment: performBatchUpdates is called once all the data is loaded in the collection view and when a new set of data is needed to be loaded.i do performBatchUpdates to delete the section and remove the collectionview,assign it to nil and then reinitialize it.

Comment: when you are removing collection view, are you removing the collection layout as well? That can be a source of your problem.

Comment: i tried that but dos'nt work